# Как проверить sub() на true/false, и возможно ли это?

Tags: perl

Введённые в определённой последовательности 2 аргумента при запуске программы выполняют функции в определённой последовательности:

```
perl -le 'sub foo{print 1} sub bar{print 2} my%f=(-q=>\&foo, -w=>\&bar); $f{$_}->() for @ARGV' -- -q -w
```

Напечатает:

```
1
2
```

---

```
perl -le 'sub foo{print 1} sub bar{print 2} my%f=(-q=>\&foo, -w=>\&bar); $f{$_}->() for @ARGV' -- -w -q
```

Напечатает:

```
2
1
```

---

Например, я хочу, если юзер ввёл `-w -q`, не запускать ни одну функцию. Блин, или как проверить функцию на тру/фолс, и исходя из этого выполнять следующую функцию или нет?

Comment: что значит "проверить функцию на true/false" ? ваши функции сейчас возвращают undef. Так что они заведомо false (это если вы говорите о результате функции, а не о чем то другом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно что-то возвращать из функции. Например:

```perl
sub foo {
    print 'foo';
    return 1;
}
sub bar {
    print 'bar';
    return;
}
```

И, соответственно, выходить из цикла, если функция вернула `ложь`:

```perl
$f{$_}->() or last for @ARGV;
```